# Using TIBDataset how do I set a DateTime field to null

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

TField.Clear does not work on a DateTime field, like it does for say an integer field.
So how do I set the field to null?

I'm using Delphi 2010.

Currently I do this;

```
IBDataset1.FieldByName('EUL_START_DATE').Clear;
```

However the field does not get set to null, it still contains a date value.

I think this explains it, but i don't want to go messing with core delphi files.
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=78920

What if i need to reinstall Rad Studio. I would have to remember all these little patches.

Comment: can you show the code ?

Comment: `TField.Clear` does indeed work for datetime fields. Please [edit] to include your code, and be more clear about how it "does not work".

Comment: You need to `IBDataset1.Edit; IBDataset1.FieldByName('EUL_START_DATE').Clear; IBDataset1.Post;`

Comment: Yes, sorry I thought that would go without saying. If we want to edit a dataset we need to be in edit mode. If we want changes to persist we need to post. However the field value should still change before we post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the unit IBCustomDataset from line 3480 comment out the following lines;

```
//if TIBStringField(Field).EmptyAsNull then
//  rdFields[FMappedFieldPosition[Field.FieldNo - 1]].fdIsNull := True
//else
//begin
//  rdFields[FMappedFieldPosition[Field.FieldNo - 1]].fdDataLength := 0;
//  rdFields[FMappedFieldPosition[Field.FieldNo - 1]].fdIsNull := False;
//end
```

and add in the following lines;

```
//NewCode IbCustomDataSet.pas Line 3480
begin
  if (Field is TIBStringField) and
    (not TIBStringField(Field).EmptyAsNull) then
  begin
    rdFields[FMappedFieldPosition[Field.FieldNo -  1]].fdDataLength := 0;
    rdFields[FMappedFieldPosition[Field.FieldNo - 1]].fdIsNull := False;
  end
  else
    rdFields[FMappedFieldPosition[Field.FieldNo - 1]].fdIsNull := True;
end
//End New Code
```

solution found here;
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=78920

Tested, seem to work ok.

Just remember to make a note if you need to reinstall rad studio, this patch will need to be re-applied.

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).